# How to take the derivative of a function w.r.t. just one of the arguments?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

When I use

```
DSolve[
  D[v[ω, z, Subscript[k, y], Subscript[k, x]], {z, 1}] == 
    -((i*ω)/c)*(Sqrt[1 - (c*Subscript[k, y]/ω)^2] + 
    Sqrt[1 - (c*Subscript[k, x]/ω)^2])*v[ω, z, Subscript[k, y], Subscript[k, x]],
v, z]
```

to determine the general solutions of this differential equation, I get an error message which says that the length of the derivative operator is not the same as the number of arguments. However, the derivative on the LHS of the differential equation is only w.r.t. the $z$ argument, so I do not know how to overcome this problem.

Comment: Hi and welcome.  As good programming practice, try to avoid using subscripted objects as variables, since they are not always treated as symbols by *Mathematica* and may lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: To see such unexpected behaviour, try this: `D[f[x, Subscript[x, 1]], x]`.  As you can see, `D` treated `Subscript` as a mathematical function that has `x` as an argument.

Comment: `MMM`s answer assumes that `i` in your equation is the square root of -1. I am guessing that is what you probably meant. That (and dropping the subscript) is the difference between `MMM`s answer and `Fabians`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to put in the function v with its arguments:

```
DSolve[D[v[ω, z, Subscript[k, y], Subscript[k, x]], {z, 
    1}] == -((i*ω)/c)*(Sqrt[
      1 - (c*Subscript[k, y]/ω)^2] + 
     Sqrt[1 - (c*Subscript[k, x]/ω)^2])*
   v[ω, z, Subscript[k, y], Subscript[k, x]], 
 v[ω, z, Subscript[k, y], Subscript[k, x]], z]
```

Gives:

> ```
>  {{v[ω, z, Subscript[k, y], Subscript[k, x]] -> 
>    E^((z*(-(i*ω*Sqrt[(ω^2 - c^2*Subscript[k, x]^2)/ω^2]) - 
>         i*ω*Sqrt[(ω^2 - c^2*Subscript[k, y]^2)/ω^2]))/c)*C[1]}}
> ```

or as TeX

$$\left\{\left\{v\left(\omega ,z,k_y,k_x\right)\to c_1 \exp \left(\frac{z \left(-i
   \omega  \sqrt{\frac{\omega ^2-c^2 k_x^2}{\omega ^2}}-i \omega  \sqrt{\frac{\omega
   ^2-c^2 k_y^2}{\omega ^2}}\right)}{c}\right)\right\}\right\}$$